# What is the purpose of signifyd.fingerprint block in checkout page in magento2?

Tags: magento2

what is the purpose of "signifyd.fingerprint" block on checkout page in magento2

I have checked in

> /var/www/html/name/vendor/magento/module-signifyd/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

Comment: you should check the `README.md` file under `vendor/magento/module-signifyd/` directory

Comment: Yes i have already read it. But I want to do do checkout optimization  which taking 7sec to load in which 1sec taken by fingerprint.phtml

Answer (score 1):

Device fingerprinting.

Is signify a service you use?

You could explore disabling. Sorry I don't know how tightly coupled it is to the framework.